# Retrofit2: Protect baseUrl

Tags: android, retrofit2, reverse-engineering, source-code-protection

I am using `Retrofit2` for API calls via my Android app:

```
Api api = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL) //<-- Problem here
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(okHttpClient.build())
            .build()
            .create(Api.class);
```

Nowadays, many apps are being re-uploaded to the store by just changing the **BASE_URL** needed or with some minimal re-skinning.
I know that protecting to 100% an app from Reverse Engineering is impossible, but I just want to somehow make it harder for anyone to just change the **BASE_URL** and use the app with his own API.

For the **BASE_URL** itself, I am getting it with some native code as explained [here](https://medium.com/programming-lite/securing-api-keys-in-android-app-using-ndk-native-development-kit-7aaa6c0176be). But still, anyone can put whatever he/she wants in `baseUrl(BASE_URL)` and he/she is good to go.

For now, I am thinking to import the whole `Retrofit2` as a module in my project and modify there to add some level of obscurity.

But I am just wandering, isn't there any better way to do it?

Thanks.